# How to unit test method which uses static classes, without Moles or Isolator?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, refactoring

I have a method

```
     public int GetHighestPriorityPriceRecordIndex(SearchAndExtractReply_2 priceInfoReply)
    {
        int index = 0;

        var priceExposableColumn = GetPriceColumn(priceInfoReply, "LPCIsPriceExposable");

        var pricingSourceIDColumn = GetPriceColumn(priceInfoReply, "LPCPricingSourceID");

        var priceExposablePriority = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "Y", 2 }, { "N", 1 } };

        var pricingSourcePriority = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "USA", 5 }, { "EME", 4 }, { "ASI", 3 }, { "DER", 2 }, { "NUS", 1 } };

        if (priceExposableColumn.Value != null)
            for (int i = 1; i < priceExposableColumn.Value.Length; i++)
                if (priceExposablePriority[priceExposableColumn.Value[i]] > priceExposablePriority[priceExposableColumn.Value[index]]
                    && pricingSourcePriority[pricingSourceIDColumn.Value[i]] > pricingSourcePriority[pricingSourceIDColumn.Value[index]])
                    index = i;

        return index;
    }

    private static StringColumn GetPriceColumn(SearchAndExtractReply_2 priceInfoReply, string columnName)
    {
        return (StringColumn)SearchAndExtractReply_2_Extension.GetColumn(priceInfoReply, columnName);
    }
```

I want to unit test the class that has this method, this method uses static classes and method
SearchAndExtractReply_2_Extension.GetColumn.
How better way to refactor this code in the way that I can test this method without Moles or Isolator? Or better to use Moles to isolate the code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with refactoring if you can. Bringing Moles in sounds like bit of an overkill, considering you still have options to make small code change.

And about that refactoring. Introduce a new class which sole responsibility will be to extract column from `SearchAndExtractReply_2` object. It's fairly simple:

```
public interface IColumnExtractor
{
    StringColumn GetPriceColumn(SearchAndExtractReply_2 source,
        string columnName);
}

public class ColumnExtractor : IColumnExtractor
{
    public StringColumn GetPriceColumn(SearchAndExtractReply_2 source, 
        string columnName)
    {
        return (StringColumn)SearchAndExtractReply_2_Extension.GetColumn(source, 
            columnName);
    }
}
```

Now, either provide such class instance to your original method (adding new parameter of type `IColumnExtractor`), or provide the very same extractor to entire class (for example via *constructor injection*).

```
public int GetHighestPriorityPriceRecordIndex(
    SearchAndExtractReply_2 priceInfoReply, IColumnExtractor columnExtractor)
{
    // use extractor object instead of static method
}
```

Then you're good to go with any free mocking framework (like [FakeItEasy](http://code.google.com/p/fakeiteasy/) or [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)).

Answer (score 2):

If your depending on something it should be passed in to the method. Then your API is clear and you can tell from the outside what is needed and what can be mocked. This means that you separate construction logic and business logic. When combined with a dependency injection framework like Unity or Castle it will give you nice testable code in your unit tests and code that's easy to use in production.

I would create an interface for your `SearchAndExtractReply_2_Extension` and then pas that as a parameter to `GetHighestPriorityPriceRecordIndex` (or maybe to the constructor if it's used in multiple places). Then you can mock the whole dependency or pass the 'real implementation' into it when doing integration testing.

Comment: Yes, that will help in making your code clearer and it will give you seams where you can insert a mock to make sure you can test your code in isolation.

Comment: the problem is that I am working in a big legacy solution and include IoC container will need refactor a lots and tonns of code.

Comment: An ioc container is not a requirement If you modify your constructor you only have to fix the compile errors and include the extra parameter